# Drawing using curveTo

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

The task is to draw custom shape using `curveTo` graphics method.

The problem is that paths joins are not exact.

Result is:

[image: callout]

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            test.graphics.clear();
            test.graphics.lineStyle(1);
            drawBorder(test.graphics, 200, 200);
        }

        private function drawBorder(g: Graphics, width: Number, height: Number): void
        {
            var cornerRadius: int = 20;
            var pointerWidth: int = 4;
            var pointerHeight: int = 10;
            var pointerBottomGap: int = 6;

            width -= pointerWidth;

            g.moveTo(0, height - cornerRadius);
            g.lineTo(0, cornerRadius + 1);
            g.curveTo(0, 0, cornerRadius, 0);
            g.lineTo(width - cornerRadius, 0);
            g.curveTo(width, 0, width, cornerRadius);
            var pointerY: int = height - pointerHeight - pointerBottomGap;
            g.lineTo(width, pointerY);
            g.lineTo(width + pointerWidth, pointerY + pointerHeight);
            g.lineTo(width - pointerWidth, pointerY + pointerHeight + 1);
            g.curveTo(width - pointerWidth, height, width - cornerRadius, height);
            g.lineTo(cornerRadius, height);
            g.curveTo(0, height, 0, height - cornerRadius);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:UIComponent 
    id="test"
    x="100" y="100"/>
```

The question could be rephrased - How to draw rect with corner radius using `curveTo` method?

Comment: I suppose this is some kind of exercise? Cause it's much, much easier to draw basic shapes like this using primitives.

Comment: No, it is real task. It is design of chat message, so it need to be resizable. How could I reach that condition using primitives?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the shape consists of a rounded Rect and a small triangle in the lower left corner. That said, if it needs to be scalable, you're gonna have a hard time keeping the triangle in the right place. You'll probably be better of using [Path](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/primitives/Path.html). I'll see if I can convert your code.

Comment: I don't understand how to do resizable path. Path could be like 'M 10 50 L 10 100...', so values are hardcoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to the odd anti-aliasing, try turning on pixel hinting:

```
targetSprite.graphics.lineStyle(1.0, 0x000000, 1.0, true);
```

Comment: It helps. The result is good. Could it be better?
Comparision https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2147606/test2.png. First image - `pixelHinting` is true, second - false;

Answer (score 3):

Increasing the thickness of the line stroke weight will help; as well, try specifying caps and joint:

[image: callout]

```
import flash.display.CapsStyle;
import flash.display.JointStyle;
import flash.display.LineScaleMode;

graphics.lineStyle(2,
                   0x0,
                   1.0,
                   true,
                   LineScaleMode.NORMAL,
                   CapsStyle.SQUARE,
                   JointStyle.MITER);

drawBorder(graphics, 200, 200);
```

Comment: Yes increasing the thickness helps, but I couldn't change it because of design.